# C program to print home directory showing "grep: (standard input): Bad file descriptor"

Tags: c, grep, pipe, file-descriptor

I am getting "grep: (standard input): Bad file descriptor" when running the following code. Any idea why? The program is supposed to print out your home directory. Thanks!

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>

int main(void) {
pid_t childpid;
int fd[2];

if(pipe(fd) == -1) { /* setup a pipe */
    perror("Failed to setup pipeline");
    return 1;
}
if((childpid = fork()) == -1){ /* fork a child */
    perror("Failed to fork a child");
    return 1;
}
if(childpid == 0){ /* env is the child */

    if(dup2(fd[1],STDOUT_FILENO)==-1)
        perror("Failed to redirect stdout of env");
    else if(close(fd[0] == -1)) /* close unused file descriptor */
        perror("Failed to close extra pipe descriptors on env");
    else {
        execl("/usr/bin/env", "env", NULL); /* execute env */
        perror("Failed to exec env");
    }
    return 1;
}
if(dup2(fd[0],STDIN_FILENO)==-1) 
/*grep is the parent*/
    perror("Failed to redirect stdin of grep");
else if(close(fd[1]==-1))
    perror("Failed to close extra pipe file descriptors on grep");
else {
    execl("/bin/grep", "grep", "HOME", NULL); /*execute "grep HOME"*/
    perror("Failed to exec grep");
}
return 1;
}
```

Comment: In the first test, should that be if(pipe(fd[0]) == -1) {}   ? As the address of fd would not be an appropriate descriptor

Comment: what does `grep HOME` do exactly? are you missing a file name there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The errors are at theses 2 lines:

```
else if(close(fd[0] == -1))
...
else if(close(fd[1]==-1))
```

It should be :

```
else if(close(fd[0]) == -1)
...
else if(close(fd[1]) == -1)
```

Otherwise getting HOME env can be realized without executing external program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv, char** envp)
{
    char** env;
    for (env = envp; *env != 0; env++)
    {
        char* thisEnv = *env;
        if (strncmp(thisEnv, "HOME=", 5) == 0)
        {
            printf("%s\n", thisEnv + 5);
            break;
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: What about `#include <stdlib.h>` and `const char *home = getenv("HOME");`?